# Action not passed to Reducer in Redux using React

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am writing a code to apply a theme using redux.
Here is my code:

Actions/index.js

```
export const CHANGE_THEME = 'CHANGE_THEME';

export const changeTheme = (payload) => {
  console.log('payload ' + payload)
  return ({
  type: CHANGE_THEME,
  payload
})}
```

Reducers/index.js

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import themeChangeHandler from './themeChangeHandler'

const rightBarMenuHandler = combineReducers({
  themeChangeHandler
})

export default rightBarMenuHandler
```

themeChangeHandler.js

```
const themeChangeHandler = (state = 'light', action) => {
   console.log('rec action ' + action.type)

  switch(action.type) {
    case 'CHANGE_THEME':
      return action.payload

    default:
      return state
  }
}

export default themeChangeHandler
```

The event is using Menu/MenuItem

```
class AppBarRightButtonsMenu extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
          super(props);
        }
        onClickButton = (data) => {
          this.props.dispatch(changeTheme('dark'))
        }
        render() {
          const {onThemeChange, onLogout, dispatch} = this.props;
          var i = 1;
          if(NavigationButtonMenu) {
            var list = NavigationButtonMenu.map( (menuItem) => {
              return <MenuItem key={i++} primaryText={menuItem.name} onClick = {this.onClickButton}/>;
              });
                return <Menu >{list}</Menu>;
              } else {
                return <div/>
              }
     }
  }
export default connect()(AppBarRightButtonsMenu);
```

App.js

```
const App = ({theme}) => (
   <SomeComp
      theme={theme}
   />
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  console.log('state.themeChangeHandler ' + state.themeChangeHandler)
    return {
        theme: state.themeChangeHandler === 'dark'?darkBaseTheme:customTheme,
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null) (App);
```

Adding store

```
const store = createStore(reducers)
ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}>
  <App />
</Provider>, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

I just get the console logs in the action but not the one in reducer(i get test log of reducer on the bootup). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where have you created the store

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you setup your store? You've "combined" your reducers, but you haven't wired up the store yet.

```
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

// create the store from the reducers
const store = createStore(combineReducers(/*...your reducers here...*/));

// You probably want to let your components have access to the store's state.
const AppWithStore = (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>
);

ReactDOM.render(<AppWithStore />, document.getElementById('whatever'));
```

Once you set this all up, you can access the store state like you do in the `App` component.

You can find more information about the `Provider` component in the Redux bindings for React [documentation](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html#passing-the-store).

Once you're comfortable with that, I would suggest going over Dan Abramov's excellent [course on idiomatic Redux](https://egghead.io/courses/building-react-applications-with-idiomatic-redux), which mentions a few tricks you can do with the store and the store state in the first videos.

Comment: Are there any errors in the console? Are you sure you're combining reducers properly. The `combineReducers` function needs an object. In your case it has to be `combineReducers({ themeHandler })` so that the state will be accessible under the `themeHandler` key. The following code works for me: https://gist.github.com/gkats/ad67323bc887c94d63982746bdbceed4

Comment: The problem was I am using Admin-On-Rest framework and reducers have to be added to the Admin component. Once I did that it worked. Thanks for your help