# Data is not passing from action to reducer, on using react-redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, axios

I am calling API in action and have to pass those action to reducer. But data from action is not passing to the reducer. I am not using combined-reducer either.

src/index.js is

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import PrescriptionIndex from './components/prescriptionIndex.jsx';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import reducer from './reducer';

const store = createStore(reducer);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <PrescriptionIndex />
  </Provider>, document.getElementById("root")
)
```

This is my component PrescriptionIndex.jsx

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { index_prescription } from '../action/index.js';
import { connect } from  'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';

class PrescriptionIndex extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      prescription: null
    }
  }
    
  action_call(){
    index_prescription();
  }

  render(){
    this.state.prescription === null ? this.action_call() : null
    return(
      <div>
        PrescriptionIndex
      </div>
    )
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
  return bindActionCreators({index_prescription}, dispatch)
}

function mapStateToProps( state ){
  return {
    profiles: state
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(PrescriptionIndex);
```

I am calling index function as `index_prescription();` in `action_call()`.

And my action is

```js
import {ADD_PRESCRIPTION} from '../constant.js';
import axios from 'axios';
import dispatch from 'axios';

export const index_prescription = () => {
  const base_url= "http://localhost:3000/api/v1/";
  const fetch_url = `${base_url}/prescriptions`;
  axios.get(fetch_url)
    .then(response => {
      dispatch({type: ADD_PRESCRIPTION, details: response.data})
    })
}
```

Reducer is

```js
import {ADD_PRESCRIPTION} from '../constant.js';

const profiles = (state=[], action) => {
  let profiles = null;
  switch(action.type){
    case ADD_PRESCRIPTION:
      profiles = [...state, action.details]
      return profiles;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default profiles;
```

constant.js is

```js
export const ADD_PRESCRIPTION = "ADD_PRESCRIPTION";
```

I have verified all the [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46579686/action-not-passed-to-reducer-in-redux-using-react), but cant able to study whats going wrong in my code.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React Native Redux: Action dispatched, return results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41981460/react-native-redux-action-dispatched-return-results)

Comment: I have read the answer you stated Sir. The answer explains how reducers and action works. But, I have a problem of passing data from action to reducers.

Answer (score 0):

You miss following code..

```js
import {ADD_PRESCRIPTION} from '../constant.js';
import axios from 'axios';
import dispatch from 'axios';

export const index_prescription = () => {
return dispatch=>{
  const base_url= "http://localhost:3000/api/v1/";
  const fetch_url = `${base_url}/prescriptions`;
  axios.get(fetch_url)
    .then(response => {
      dispatch({type: "ADD_PRESCRIPTION", details: response.data})
    })
 }   
}
```

Comment: I have tried this, but now its not fetching the data from API

Answer (score 0):

You are calling dispatch from axions? Is not part of react-redux? 
If you use `redux-promise-middleware` you can do this:

```
import {ADD_PRESCRIPTION} from '../constant.js';
import axios from 'axios';
import dispatch from 'axios';

export const index_prescription = () => {
  const base_url= "http://localhost:3000/api/v1/";
  const fetch_url = `${base_url}/prescriptions`;
  return {
    type: "ADD_PRESCRIPTION",
    details: axios.get(fetch_url)
      .then(response => {
        return response;
      }) 
 }   
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Sir. I will check about redux-promise-middleware and let you know about it. But, the changes you stated in the code doesnt return data to reducers sir.